# Automatically change status of post Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In my rails application I have a job model which I want the status to be changed automatically to "archived" after 30 days from approval by the admin is this possible? if so what is the way to do it?

Comment: You need to make a rake task

Comment: I've voted to close this question, because I think it's too broad for SO. However, if you look at the [Rails Guide for Active Job](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html), you might get some ideas.

Comment: @Cyzanfar So if I create a task it will be run automatically or i must run it every day myself sorry for this question but I have never worked with tasks

Answer (score 1):

I would add an attribute named "archive_time" as a datetime when it enters the approved state.
Then you can set up a rake task to set the archived state and where the archive_time is in the past. This might look like this:

```
jobs = Job.where("state = ? and archive_time >= ?", 'approved', Time.now)
jobs.each {|job| job.archive }
```

Then schedule the rake task to be run once a day. I would use cron to achieve this.

Comment: Also, the "whenever" gem is a good way to manage rails cron jobs.

Answer (score 1):

A rake task or background job (such as Active Job or Delayed Job ) can do the trick however you might not need them in this case. If you are dealing with timestamps in your database, you can create a scope or a method to mark jobs as archived.

For instance, if you have a column named `approved_at` that is a `datetime`. When you approve a job, you set the `approved_at = Time.now`.

Now you can create a method that indicates if the job is archived:

```
def is_archived?
  approved_at && approved_at < Time.now - 30.days
end
```

And to get all the archived jobs, you can create a scope:

```
scope :archived, -> { where('approved_at IS NOT NULL AND approved_at <?', Time.now - 30.days)}
```

Comment: Hi this is partially working but I still have a issue is that I have a column named jobstatus in the job table and i want to be changed to "archived" when the Job is archived

Comment: With what I proposed you wouldn't need the `job_status` column anymore (that is if you only have 3 states: not approved, approved and archived)