# Best way to automatically update a field in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a status field that is a list generated from an array.  I have a last updated datetime field that is updated when the record is accessed and changed in any way.  What I need to do is determine any record that hasn't has an update in the last 30 days and automatically update the status field to pending.  This would be done at least weekly, but likely at the end of each day.

Cron job itself is not available.  I have access to Delayed_job, but I am not clear if I can make it do what I need to do.  What are some other ways to get this done?

Comment: You can easily do this using cron job. Write a rake task and call it weekly(or daily) via cron job. You can also use 'whenever' gem for this.

Comment: Do you need the `status` field? Can't the `status` be inferred from the `last_updated` field? This is dependant on your logic, but check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30132601/2697183)

Comment: The status field is not a date, it is something like Quoted, PO Received, etc.  I am going to add a specific status for orders that don't have a specific status within 30 days of the last updated datetime.

Answer (score 0):

First of all running task in background and running any task at specific time on specific intervals are two different things.

Delayed job helps us to run any task in background depending on priority of the task.

On the other hand cron job helps us to run a task daily, monthly, weekly or at any particular time of day.

You need to write a task to fetch all the records which are not updated in last 30 days and to update their status. Then you need to use scheduling plugins like [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) or [clockwork](https://github.com/adamwiggins/clockwork) to schedule the job to run at desired time.

You have to write rake task something like:

```
task :update_records => :environment do
  my_records = MyModel.where('updated_at <= ?', Time.now - 30.days)
  # Do your operations here on my records
end
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513058/how-do-i-use-rails-clockwork-gem-to-run-rake-tasks) for clockwork or [this](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-to-schedule-tasks-using-whenever/) for whenever to schedule your task.
Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, looks like whenever is available.  I will check that out and see what I can do.